# Implementing ASP.NET MVC5 Identity without creating another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

I'm using Entity Framework `DBFirst`. My Users table has this format:

> id,email,fn,ln,password,role.

So basically, a user can be either client or admin.
I've succesfully implemented Identity using this tutorial http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1 but I have no idea what should I do next. I want to use this format of the db, without creating another table.

> I want this: if you are a client, you can only go to 2 pages. If you
>   are an admin, you are free to do whatever you want on the page. If you
>   are not logged in, you are forced to log in if you want to navigate on
>   the site. (did this)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure after quick googling you can find a tutorial , basically you just override a couple of classes that connects the user obects to the db context

Comment: Can you show us what you've got now? If not, Scott's advice is the one to take;

Comment: I am sure you can find something here. This is recommended resources for asp net mvc identity http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources

Answer (score 0):

You could add the columns from the first table by adding them as columns in the User table before migration(but remember, you cannot have two Id´s with the same name of course):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string email {get;set;}
    //The rest o
}
```

And to control who can access what set the data annotation above the actions that you want a specific identity group to be able to access like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
 public ActionResult AdminsOnlyPage()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

And if you want to keep the entire class from not logged in persons, add the data annotation to class level(without specifying a user or role), which would keep all actions unreachable until one is logged in:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyClass
{}
```